# Как можно передать номера полей строки,для последующей обработки в цикле в PowerShell

Tags: windows, cmd, bat, powershell

Пример:
У меня есть следующий вывод команды,которая обнаруживает диски:

```
/dev/sda -d ata # /dev/sda, ATA device
```

Мне надо получать первые два значения - `/dev/*` и тип диска (ata)
В `cmd` это выглядит так:

```
for /F "tokens=1,3" %%a in ('C:\"Program Files"\smartmontools\bin\smartctl.exe —scan') ^
do echo echo %%a
```

Как тоже самое сделать в `powershell`?
Спасибо!

PS: Пробовал делить строку через `split`, после дергать значения, получилось, но дисков может быть огромное количество, поэтому этот вариант отпадает, именно номера полей хотелось бы получать.

Comment: `C:\"Program Files"\smartmontools\bin\smartctl.exe —scan | % {,-split$_} | % {$_[0,2]-join' '}`

Comment: Все-таки split,пойду читать про синтаксис,огромное спасибо,@PetSerAl !

Comment: @zubat опишите более детально какие строки вы получаете, в каком виде, или какой командой и какие хотите иметь на выходе, я вам помогу.

Answer (score 0):

```
('/dev/sda -d ata # /dev/sda, ATA device' -split ' ')[0,2]
```

или

```
$string = '/dev/sda -d ata # /dev/sda, ATA device'
($string -split ' ')[0,2]
```